# Illegal Indirection in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, iterator

I can't figure out why I get an illegal indirection error :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1 = "";
    stack<char> s;
    unordered_map<char, char> m;

    m.insert('(', ')');
    m.insert('{', '}');
    m.insert('[', ']');

    for (auto x : s1)
    {
        if (m.find(x) != m.end()) s.push(x);

        else 
        {
            auto it = m.find(s.top());
            if (s.empty() || (it->second) != x) { cout << "Invalid\n"; s.pop(); break; } 
        }

    }

}
```

it is an iterator to a map entry and I am trying to access its value.

Comment: This will cause undefined behaviour if `s1` contains something that doesn't start with a bracket, because you call `s.top()` on an empty stack

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to correct your insertion into `unordered_map<>` as follows:

```
m.insert(std::make_pair('(', ')'));
m.insert(std::make_pair('{', '}'));
m.insert(std::make_pair('[', ']'));
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2fff8b2f36ebc3c

A few more options  for insertion into `unordered_map<>`:

```
m.emplace('(', ')');
m.emplace('{', '}');
m.emplace('[', ']');
```

OR

```
m.insert(std::pair<char,char>('(', ')'));
m.insert(std::pair<char,char>('{', '}'));
m.insert(std::pair<char,char>('[', ']'));
```

**EDIT**

One more option:

```
m.emplace(std::make_pair('(', ')'));
m.emplace(std::make_pair('{', '}'));
m.emplace(std::make_pair('[', ']'));
```

Comment: is there only this way to insert in a map in c++ ?

Comment: @adrian008 No, you can also use [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace).

Comment: @adrian008 if you have C++11 compiler `emplace` is preferable , it will create the object in place. Others will create the pair object and copy/move

Comment: @Steephen I actually tried all 3 in an Online Judge problem and found out that all things remaining the same, make_pair had the best performance (20 ms) while emplace was the slowest (32 ms). And I am able to use C++11 in that Judge (i can use range based for loops). Do you think it is the correct inference, I am making ?

Comment: @adrian008 that is interesting!!!. As in case of performance,  measurement is the criteria for final decision making. As I said so, I will give one more options as answer by an edit, please try that also.

Comment: @Steephen Thanks, I tried the new option, it is slower than emplace in the same Online Judge.

Answer (score 4):

There is another way to "insert" into a map that the original answer hasn't noted which is with the `[]` operator:

```
m['('] = ')';
m['{'] = '}';
m['['] = ']';
```